# Meteor: Force rendering an element

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a generic template used several times in my app:

```
<template name="genericCollapse">
  {{data-1}}
  <a href=# class='collapsed' data-toggle='collapse'
     data-target='#uniqueId'>Show/hide data-2</a>
  <div class='collapse' id='uniqueId'>
    {{data-2}}
  </div>
</template>
```

By clicking somewhere else in the app, data-1 and data-2 change simultaneously (using Session Vars). However, in case the template is already on the screen, only data-1 and data-2 are changing but the collapse status of the div remains (obviously) unchanged. If it was open before, it remains open.

I want to achieve, that whenever data-1/data-2 changes, div as well as a are forced to be in status collapsed again.
I tried to add

```
<a href=# class='{{collapsed}}'

Template.genericCollapse.helpers({
  collapsed () {return "collapsed " + Random.Id()},
})
```

which is not only pretty ugly but also does not help, because the class of div still remains "collapse show" and even with a second helper for div, I can't get rid of "show".

Re-rendering the whole Template would be also acceptable, but I have difficulties to determine the parentNode for calling Blaze.render() - it is never the same - and I'm also not sure where to place such a call correctly.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're fighting with bootstrap. The `show` class is added by bootstrap when you click on the link, correct? Because this class is not set by your html markup you need to remove it yourself when your underlying data changes. You can do by observing changes to your data and then modifying the DOM directly.

Here's a basic example:

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function () {
  const query = MyCollection.find({},{fields: {data-1: 1, data-2: 1}});
  const handle = query.observeChanges({
    changed(id, fields) {
      $('.show').removeClass('show');
    }
});
```

This assumes that there's a collection with fields `data-1` and `data-2` that you want to control off of. If your `data-1` and `data-2` are helpers that are performing some computations then you might want to approach this with a `Tracker` based on reactive vars instead.

Answer (score 1):

@Michel Floyd is right about fighting bootstrap.

However, since you said you're using `Session` vars, just use an autorun instead:

```
Template.genericCollapse.onRendered(function() {
  this.autorun(() => {
    const data1 = Session.get('data-1');
    const data2 = Session.get('data-2');
    if (data1 === someCondition || data2 === someOtherCondition) {
      this.$('.collapse').collapse('show');
    } else {
      this.$('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

Any time either `data-1` or `data-2` changes, this function will re-run

Comment: This is the right answer for Session/reactive vars.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for your help!

@Michel Floyd let me realize that my issue is not caused by anything related to Meteor, but by bootstrap.

@Fred Stark added a nice variation to the solution, he uses autorun which is more Meteor-style and he uses .collapse('hide') instead of .removeClass('show') which gives some nice fade-out effect at least on iOS.

Because I've mixed up several issues, I'll clarify it one by one:

**Find a trigger:** You could use autorun or observeChanges as suggested, but both is not necessary in the end, because a Meteor helper is always called.
First try:

```
<a href=# class='{{collapsed}}'

Template.genericCollapse.helpers({
  collapsed () {return "collapsed"},
})
```

The code in this helper will always run, when something in the template changes. If data-1 or data-2 changes for any reason, code will be excuted, so this is my trigger.

**Use helpers properly:** The first try doesn't do anything on the html, because the spacebar {{collapsed}} does not change its content. Although the helper code is executed, the return value does not change and therefore has no effect on the html side.
In order to see any change, return value must be different each time.
Second try:

```
Template.genericCollapse.helpers({
  collapsed () {return "collapsed " + Random.Id()},
})
```

Ugly as I already said, but at least it sets the correct class for a.

**Get rid of "show":** And here comes Michel: Because "show" in div is controlled by Bootstrap, you cannot control this with any kind of spacebar/helper - but with javascript.
Third try:

```
Template.genericCollapse.helpers({
  collapsed () {
    $('.show').removeClass('show');
    return "collapsed " + Random.Id()},
})
```

This works! It might be necessary to narrow down '.show' in case other elements having class "show" are present, but that's the way to go.

**Prettify:** Having Random.Id() as a class is still bad. So let's treat a the same way like we treated div. Additionally, we should use the "uniqueId" as identifier for both.
Fourth try:

```
Template.genericCollapse.helpers({
  collapsed () {
    $('[data-target="#uniqueId"]').addClass('collapsed');
    $('#uniqueId').removeClass('show');
    return "collapsed"},
})
```

**Make it shiny:** There is no need for the helper {{collapsed}} to return any value anymore, this is all done with javascript. We just need the trigger functionality, so this is the final code:

```
<template name="genericCollapse">
  {{data-1}}
  <a href=# class='collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' {{hook}}
     data-target='#uniqueId'>Show/hide data-2</a>
  <div class='collapse' id='uniqueId'>
    {{data-2}}
  </div>
</template>

Template.genericCollapse.helpers({
  hook () {
    $('[data-target="#uniqueId"]').addClass('collapsed');
    $('#uniqueId').removeClass('show');
  }
})
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this the meteor way by returning the class to the element from a helper like so:

**template:**

```
<template name="genericCollapse">
  {{data-1}}
  <a href=# class={{isCollapsed}} data-toggle='collapse'
     data-target='#uniqueId'>Show/hide data-2</a>
...
...
</template>
```

**Helper:**

```
Template.genericCollapse.helpers({

isCollapsed: function(){

    if()// logic to check if it needs to be collapsed
       return "collapsed"
    else
       return "collapse"
    }
});
```